# Linq to select most recent file by relative file path

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists of files, one from a local drive and one from a remote drive.  The files are arranged in the same relative path locations and I want to combine the two lists into one that contains only the files that have the same relative paths in both lists.  I also want to make sure that there are no duplicates in the result list, but that the file that has the greater timestamp at the relative path gets selected into the final list.

My lists are called localDetails and remoteDetails, are of type SyncFile, and have members RelativeFilePath and ModifyDate.

I have tried using an intersect with a custom equality comparer that only looked at relative file path, but couldnt figure out how to select the maximum timetamp from the collision.  I have also tried to use Concat and then GroupBy but couldnt get it to work.

Comment: Post the code you tried to do. Maybe we can point you to the error, instead of giving you the solution _as is_. You shouldn't be far from the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
var results = localDetails.Join(remoteDetails, 
     lf => lf.RelativeFilePath, 
     rf => rf.RelativeFilePath, 
     (lf, rf) => lf.ModifyDate > rf.ModifyDate ? lf : rf);
```

This joins the two lists based on the relative file path from each list (hence the two key selectors) and then for the "result" of the two, it takes the one with the greater ModifyDate.

Just tested this on some sample data (based on your description) and it works, for example, if you had:

```
        var localDetails = new List<SyncFile> 
        {
            new SyncFile { ModifyDate = DateTime.Now, RelativeFilePath = "c:\\help", Id = 1 },
            new SyncFile { ModifyDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1), RelativeFilePath = "c:\\wow", Id = 2 },
            new SyncFile { ModifyDate = DateTime.Now, RelativeFilePath = "c:\\y", Id = 6 },
        };

        var remoteDetails = new List<SyncFile>()
        {
            new SyncFile { ModifyDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1), RelativeFilePath = "c:\\help", Id = 3 },
            new SyncFile { ModifyDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(5), RelativeFilePath = "c:\\wow", Id = 4 },
            new SyncFile { ModifyDate = DateTime.Now, RelativeFilePath = "c:\\x", Id = 5 },
        };

        var results = localDetails.Join(remoteDetails, l => l.RelativeFilePath, r => r.RelativeFilePath, (lf, rf) => lf.ModifyDate > rf.ModifyDate ? lf : rf);

        foreach(var result in results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(result.Id);
        }
```

The output would be the IDs 1 and 4 (I just added ID so I'd know which was which for testing purposes).

Comment: I had this solution earlier, but thought that join did a union and only used the "result" selector to resolve duplicates.  I just wanted the properly resolved duplicates, not the difference of the two lists, and just didnt realize this was working.  Thanks!

Comment: @Michael: No worries :-) LINQ has a lot of methods with a lot of power, and it can be confusing what each does and doesn't do at times :-)